# Laravel - Carry array through map

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a model collection that I'm mapping through like this:

```
$alreadyImported = [];

$players = Players::whereNotIn('id', $alreadyImported)
                    ->get()
                    ->random(25)
                    ->pluck('id');

$groups = $players->map(function ($item, $key) use ($alreadyImported) {

    array_merge($alreadyImported, $item->id);

    $group = [
        'username' => $item['username'],
    ];

    return $group;
});

// $groups is a pivot table with group and players
```

Why does my `$globalList` always start at `[]`? How can I carry the already-merged `$globalList` to the next map iteration?

The player IDs does not matter. It's for show. I am looking to pass the array through the map iterations.

Comment: Something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `pluck()` to get IDs from the collection:

```
$ids = $players->pluck('id');
```

Or, if you just need IDs:

```
$ids = Players::where('banned', false)->pluck('id');
```

If you're going to add any other data, you don't need to merge it to some array or a collection because `map()` will create a new collection.

Finally, you don't need to use `collect()` because `get()` will return collection.

Comment: I am not looking for player IDs. I am looking to pass an array through a map iteration. The Ids was just an example.

Comment: @nn2 well, you haven't explained what exactly do you want to achieve. And as I said in the answer, you don't need to pass an array.

Comment: I clearly state it in the post. Every time a `map` iteration starts, `$globalList = []` is reinitialized as `[]`. How do I carry the merged-array over to the next iteration?

Comment: @nn2 if you want to reinvent the wheel, follow the link greener gave you in the comment.